# How to change Action Sheet Default action color only?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

I have an Action Sheet with one Default action and one Cancel action. How can I change just Default action text color?

```
var refreshAlert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Are you sure you want to clear the entire message history? \n This cannot be undone.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear message history", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    print("Handle Ok logic here")
    // how to change this text color to red?
}))

refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    print("Handle Cancel Logic here")
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Instead Change your method like below: Apple has provided red color for Destructive buttons.

```
refreshAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Clear message history", style: .Destructive, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    print("Voila !! button color is changed")
}))
```

Comment: OP is asking for changing the alert action colour that is defined with `.Default` style.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do that. However, there is bit of an ugly trick you can apply here:

1. Create an image of exactly same size as that of `UIAlertController` action sheet style button.
2. Make sure image looks like exactly same as that you want your UI to look like including text & colour.
3. Pass that image as `image` property of your `Default` action like this:

->

```
let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Clear message history", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("Handle Ok logic here")
        // how to change this text color to red?
})

let image = UIImage(named: "myButtton.png")
defaultAction.setValue(image, forKey: "image")
alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
```